# Disable swiping(idangero.us) when last item showd up

Tags: jquery, plugins, html-framework-7, swiper.js, idangero

I'm using iDangero.us swiper plugin, and i want to disable swiper when the last banner is showed in the screen. [check this link.](http://epizod.club)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/girBK.png)

```
var i = myApp.swiper(".mixed-swiper", {
        width: 626,
        spaceBetween: 22,
        slidesPerView: 2,
        freeMode: !1,
        autoplay: !1,
        loop:!1,
        freeModeMomentum: !0,
        freeModeMomentumBounce: !0,
        freeModeMomentumRatio: "1",
        freeModeMomentumVelocityRatio: "0.7",
        freeModeMomentumBounceRatio: "1",
        mousewheelControl: !0,
        mousewheelReleaseOnEdges: !1,
        mousewheelForceToAxis: !0,
        mousewheelInvert: !0,
        grabCursor:!0,
        breakpoints: {
            320: {
                width: 537
            }
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using autoplay in swiper then you need add one more parameter while initialising the swiper

```
var i = myApp.swiper(".mixed-swiper", {
        width: 626,
        spaceBetween: 22,
        slidesPerView: 2,
        freeMode: !1,
        autoplay: !1,
        loop:!1,
        freeModeMomentum: !0,
        freeModeMomentumBounce: !0,
        freeModeMomentumRatio: "1",
        freeModeMomentumVelocityRatio: "0.7",
        freeModeMomentumBounceRatio: "1",
        mousewheelControl: !0,
        mousewheelReleaseOnEdges: !1,
        mousewheelForceToAxis: !0,
        mousewheelInvert: !0,
        grabCursor:!0,
        stopOnLastSlide:true, // this stop swiper once it reaches last slider
        breakpoints: {
            320: {
                width: 537
            }
        }
})
```